# Global Ground Slope Data

Tags: data-request, geospatial

Does any open global georeferenced dataset on ground slope exist?
Precision of 0.5x0.05 degrees longitude-latitude would suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With-out a clear definition of ground slope (no Wikipedia definition), I am assuming it basically is proportional to the gradient of a topography data set. [These are available](https://topotools.cr.usgs.gov/GMTED_viewer/) at a resolution of 0.002 deg.

Ignoring earth curvature at that resolution, a simple two dimensional [numerical differentiation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation) should suffice.

Please correct me, if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea whether this is acutally the same dataset as linked to by user Grimaldi in his answer, but OpenStreetMap seems to rely on the [SRTM](https://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/) dataset by JPL to calculate its height maps and contour lines. From the release notes of the latest SRTM update (from 2014):

> Previously, SRTM data for regions outside the United States were sampled for public release at 3 arc-seconds, which is 1/1200th of a degree of latitude and longitude, or about 90 meters (295 feet). The **new data have been released with a 1 arc-second, or about 30 meters
>   (98 feet), sampling** that reveals the full resolution of the original
>   measurements.

Concerning the slope question: refer to [Using SRTM Global DEM for Slope calculation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/14750/19627) on the GIS.SX for extensive answers (some targeting ArcGIS, some not) and discussion of subtle issues when dealing with global coverage data. Just as an appetizer: there is `gdaldem slope`...